DevExpress for WinForms, closing document in tabbed view but couldnt bring back
I can close the document in document manager, but i couldn't bring back.
How can i bring my documents into the my tabbed view. I tried visible or unvisible my dockpanels but this is not desirable when i close documents one of them other document should docked to middle correctly.
Here is my code block:
private void BtnChckPlanView_CheckedChanged(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (btnChckPlanView.Checked)
    {
        // Ensure the document is part of the TabbedView and activate it
        if (!tabbedView1.Documents.Contains(document2))
        {
            tabbedView1.AddDocument(document2.Control);
        }
        tabbedView1.Controller.Activate(document2);
    }
    else
    {
        tabbedView1.BeginUpdate();
        tabbedView1.Controller.Close(document2);
        tabbedView1.EndUpdate();
    }
}

private void BtnChckSolidView_CheckedChanged(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (btnChckSolidView.Checked)
    {
        // Ensure the document is part of the TabbedView and activate it
        if (!tabbedView1.Documents.Contains(document3))
        {
            tabbedView1.AddDocument(document3.Control);
        }
        tabbedView1.Controller.Activate(document3);
    }
    else
    {
        tabbedView1.BeginUpdate();
        tabbedView1.Controller.Close(document3);
        tabbedView1.EndUpdate();
    }
}

Thank you from now.
